# Sequelize генерирует неверный запрос при включении связанных моделей

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

models/user.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.Company, { foreignKey: 'companyId', as: 'company' });
    User.belongsToMany(models.WorkingDay, { through: 'UserWorkingDays', foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'days' });
  };
  return User;
};
```

models/company.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Company.associate = function (models) {
    Company.hasMany(models.User, { as: 'employees' });
  };
  return Company;
};
```

relationshipTester.js

```
const models = require('./models');
const User = models.User;
const Company = models.Company;
const WorkingDay = models.WorkingDay;

User.findOne({
  where: { email: 'john-connor@domain.com' }, include: [{ model: Company, as: 'company' }]
})
  .then((findedUser) => {
    console.log(findedUser)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error while find user : ", err)
  });
```

При запуске кода тестера получаю ошибку:

```
error: column User.CompanyId does not exist
```

log sql запроса:

```
SELECT "User"."id", "User"."email", "User"."firstName", "User"."lastName", "User"."companyId", "User"."createdAt", "User"."updatedAt", "User"."CompanyId", "company"."id" AS "company.id", "company"."name" AS "company.name", "company"."createdAt" AS "company.createdAt", "company"."updatedAt" AS "company.updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Companies" AS "company" ON "User"."companyId" = "company"."id" WHERE "User"."email" = 'john-connor@domain.com' LIMIT 1;
```

Совет от ORM:

```
hint:
  'Perhaps you meant to reference the column "User.companyId".'
```

Comment: а в таблице есть User есть столбец CompanyId ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, там есть companyId. С маленькой буквы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил модель Company, добавив в метод hasMany такой же foreignKey

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Company.associate = function (models) {
    Company.hasMany(models.User, { foreignKey: 'companyId', as: 'employees' });
  };
  return Company;
};
```